# Errors coming up in my Android Studio application

Tags: java, android

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/database/android-database-example/ to create a database application

In my AndroidDatabaseExample class, the code is as follows:

```
package com.example.database;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class AndroidDatabaseExample extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
JCGSQLiteHelper db = new JCGSQLiteHelper(this);
List list;
ArrayAdapter myAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // drop this database if already exists
    db.onUpgrade(db.getWritableDatabase(), 1, 2);

    db.createBook(new Book("The Great Gatsby", "F. Scott Fitzgerald"));
    db.createBook(new Book("Anna Karenina", "Leo Tolstoy"));
    db.createBook(new Book("The Grapes of Wrath", "John Steinbeck"));
    db.createBook(new Book("Invisible Man", "Ralph Ellison"));
    db.createBook(new Book("Gone with the Wind", "Margaret Mitchell"));
    db.createBook(new Book("Pride and Prejudice", "Jane Austen"));
    db.createBook(new Book("Sense and Sensibility", "Jane Austen"));
    db.createBook(new Book("Mansfield Park", "Jane Austen"));
    db.createBook(new Book("The Color Purple", "Alice Walker"));
    db.createBook(new Book("The Temple of My Familiar", "Alice Walker"));
    db.createBook(new Book("The waves", "Virginia Woolf"));
    db.createBook(new Book("Mrs Dalloway", "Virginia Woolf"));
    db.createBook(new Book("War and Peace", "Leo Tolstoy"));

    // get all books
    list = db.getAllBooks();
    List listTitle = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        listTitle.add(i, list.get(i).getTitle());
    }

    myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.listText, listTitle);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // start BookActivity with extras the book id
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BookActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("book", list.get(arg2).getId());
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // get all books again, because something changed
    list = db.getAllBooks();

    List listTitle = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        listTitle.add(i, list.get(i).getTitle());
    }

    myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.listText, listTitle);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}
}
```

It comes up with a 'Cannot resolve' error for getTitle, row_layout, listText and getId.

These things are all defined and implemented in a separate class called 'Book.java', as the tutorial instructs:

```
package com.example.database;

public class Book {

private int id;
private String title;
private String author;

public Book(){}

public Book(String title, String author) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}
public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.example.database.Book [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", author=" + author
            + "]";
}
}
```

So it should be recognising these things, but it's not. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please write the whole stack trace. It is nto clear what exactly is happening.

Comment: first  "import com.example.database.R". then learn how to use List. Change List to "List<Book>" if you dont define type you can not reach methods inside Books. If you dont know these, I recommend first learn the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining your variables wrongly

```
List listTitle = new ArrayList();
```

Please change it with correct one

```
List<String> listTitle = new Arraylist<>();
```

So when you try to use one of item on your List , it will be instance of **Book POJO**

then you can use `getId` , `getTitle` and other methods you defined in your **Book** model

Comment: Ok, I removed "List listTitle = new ArrayList();" and replaced it with "List<Book> listTitle = new Arraylist<>();". I am still getting the same errors. Do I need to edit anything else?

Comment: You need to import your Book.class into your activity. If you use android studio you can use `organize imports`

Comment: Ok I've spent about 20 minutes trying to figure out what I should type to import this. I've tried typing "import com.example.database.Book;" but that says it's an unused import statement.

Comment: Are you using android studio or eclipse ?

Comment: Now I imported project to Android Studio and it is not giving any error. So first download project , then at android studio file -> new -> import project. Then import your project, it shouldn't give any error. I think your problem is caused by wrong import of your project. Please follow these steps, if it doesn't work , tell me

Comment: Yes that is working now, thanks :) Although it is not letting me run the application - the green "Run" button is greyed out and won't let me click it.

Comment: Probably it is running gradle build, after a few seconds it will be green.

Comment: Finally it's running on a phone, thanks for all the help :)